# Grails 3 list-plugins lists profiles

Tags: grails

I have installed Grails 3 by downloading and unloading the zip on CentOS 6.2.

`grails --version` shows

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.10

| Groovy Version: 2.4.7

| JVM Version: 1.7.0_111
```

`grails list-plugins` shows

```
Usage: 
     create-app [NAME] --profile=web 
     create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin 

| Available Profiles
--------------------
* angular - A profile for creating applications using AngularJS
* rest-api - Profile for REST API applications
* base - The base profile extended by other profiles
* plugin - Profile for plugins designed to work across all profiles
* web - Profile for Web applications
* web-plugin - Profile for Plugins designed for Web applications

Type 'grails help' or 'grails -h' for more information.
```

Which mostly the same as `grails list-profiles`.

I thought `list-plugins` listed all of the plugins that were available for Grails in a central repository.

Is this a bug in Grails 3.1.10? (Which is the latest version for download and the version that sdkman tries to install as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Grails commands have to be run inside an existing application or plugin, with `create-app` and `create-plugin` being exceptions, so that's what the usage message is telling you. Since `list-plugins` doesn't work outside of an existing app/plugin (I'm not sure why tbh) you're seeing this low-information response.

You can see all of the available Grails 3 plugins [here](https://grails.org/plugins.html#).